# $xy'=y\ln(xy)$ differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am really struggling with this problem. This section of my book is about solutions of differential equations through substitutions. We were taught about three methods of substitution in this section. 
The first about Homogeneous equations. where you have something like 
$$ M(x,y) + N(x,y) = 0$$
and 
$$M(tx,ty) = t^\alpha *M(x,y)\; and\; N(tx,ty) = t^\alpha *N(x,y)$$ then using the substitution u=y/x or v=x/y

the other method we learned was Bernoullis equation where you have the DE in the form 
$$\frac{dy}{dx}+P(x)y = f(x)y^n$$

and the last we learned of was Reduction to separation of variables. Where you have $$\frac{dy}{dx}=f(Ax+By+C)$$ and you use subsitutions

The problem states determine an appropriate substitution and solve
$$xy'=yln(xy)$$
I found an answer on yahoo answers but I am lost in the steps.
https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20150420091352AA9lvDl
The answer given is the same as the correct answer. Can anyone explain the steps especially the part where it transitions from $$xydu=xdy+ydx = y(u+1)dx$$ or tell me another approach.Thank you

Edit:
My teacher has told me that this problem was not of three types I mentioned above, which was confusing me as I was set on it having to be one of them. Thank you everyone for your time and solutions.

Comment: Hint: use the fact that $(x y)' = x y'+y$.

Comment: Sorry I still can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to solve $$ xy'=yln(xy)$$

We make the substitution,

$$u = ln (xy)$$

Upon differentiation we get,
$$du = (xdy + ydx)/(xy)$$
$$xy du = xdy + ydx $$

Divide by $ y$ and use the original differential equation, $ xy'=uy,$  to get:
$$xdu=x/ydy+dx$$
$$xdy/dx=uy\rightarrow x/ydy=udx$$
$$ x du = (u + 1) dx$$

Solve the separable equation,
$$du / (u + 1) = dx / x$$
$$ln (u + 1) = ln x + const$$
$$u + 1 = kx$$
$$ln (xy) + 1 = kx $$
$$ln (xy) = kx - 1 $$
$$xy = exp(kx - 1)$$
$$y = exp(kx - 1) / x$$

Comment: thank you for your time

Comment: Thanks for your attention.

Comment: this solution seems to be the most simple and intuitive for me. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

***Hint***

$$xy'=y\ln(xy)$$
$$xy'+y=y\ln(xy)+y$$
$$xy'+y=y(\ln(xy)+1)$$
$$(xy)'=\frac {xy(\ln(xy)+1)} x$$
Integrate both sides
$$\int \frac {d(xy)} {xy(\ln(xy)+1)}=\int \frac{dx}x$$
Substitute $z=xy$ for simplicity
$$\int \frac {dz} {z(\ln(z)+1)}=\int \frac{dx}x$$
Substitute $z=e^t$ and ofcourse $dz=e^tdt$
$$\int \frac {\color{red}{e^t}dt} {\color{red}{e^t}(\ln(e^t)+1)}=\int \frac{dx}x$$
Note that $\ln(e^t)=t$
$$\int \frac {dt} {(t+1)}=\ln(x) +K$$
Don't forget to substitute back $t=\ln(z)=\ln(xy)$
$$\ln(t+1)=\ln(x)+K \implies t+1=Kx \implies \ln(xy)=Kx-1$$
And finally
$$\boxed {y(x)=\frac {e^{Kx-1}} x}$$

Comment: I am sorry, I am confused about the step substituting z=e^t to get to the next step. Also I understand the steps before this, but I am not understanding the reasoning behind these steps. All the problems before this one seemed so much more simple and stated this is an homogeneous differential equations, or this is a Bernoulis equations, or this is an equation of the form f(Ax, +By +C). Then this one says determine the type of substitution. How does this relate to the 3 I had talked about

Comment: I see, thank you for your time. I will look at this more later, but now it is getting late.

Comment: thank you. I went through your approach and it makes sense, but your steps seem unintuitive to me. I guess it just comes with experience

Comment: @user577215664 in step 4, why you multiply x and divide by x?

Comment: @EM4  because I need to have $(xy)$ and not $y$ alone  at the denominator since  this is my variable of integration on the left side of the DE so that the DE is separable.

Answer (score 1):

Try the substitution $u = \ln(xy)$, so $u'=\frac{1}{x} +\frac{y'}{y}$, and after some algebra your equation becomes $u'x=u+1$ which is straightforward to solve.

Comment: thank you for your time

Answer (score 1):

Another approach to the given the ordinary differential equation

$xy' = y \ln (xy) \tag 1$

may be had by first dividing (1) through by $y$:

$x \dfrac{y'}{y} = \ln (xy), \tag 2$

then expanding out the right hand side

$x \dfrac{y'}{y} = \ln (xy) = \ln x + \ln y, \tag 3$

and recalling that

$\dfrac{y'}{y} = (\ln y)';  \tag 4$

thus (3) may be written

$x (\ln y)' = \ln y + \ln x; \tag 5$

inspection of (5) motivates the introduction of

$z = \ln y; \tag 6$

under this transformation of the dependent variable (5) becomes

$x z' = z + \ln x, \tag 7$

which after a little algebra takes the form

$z' - \dfrac{1}{x} z = \dfrac{\ln x}{x}. \tag 8$

We recognize (8) as a first order, linear, inhomogeneous ordinary differential equation of the type

$z' + P(x) z = Q(x); \tag 9$

the solution of (9) which takes the value $z(x_0) = \ln y(x_0)$ at $x = x_0$ is given by the well-known formula

$z(x) = \displaystyle \exp \left ( -\int_{x_0}^x P(s) \; ds \right ) \left  ( z(x_0) + \int_{x_0}^x \exp \left ( \int_{x_0}^s P(t) \; dt \right ) Q(s) \; ds \right ); \tag{10}$

in the present case we see that

$P(x) = -\dfrac{1}{x}, \tag {11}$

and

$\displaystyle \int_{x_0}^x -\dfrac{1}{s} \; ds = - (\ln x -\ln x_0) = -\ln \dfrac{x}{x_0} = \ln \dfrac{x_0}{x}, \tag{12}$

whence

$\displaystyle \exp \left (-\int_{x_0}^x P(s) \; ds \right ) =  \exp \left (-\int_{x_0}^x  -\dfrac{1}{s} \; ds \right )$
$= \exp \left (-\ln \dfrac{x_0}{x} \right ) = \left(\exp \left (\ln \dfrac{x_0}{x} \right ) \right )^{-1} = \left (\dfrac{x_0}{x} \right )^{-1} = \dfrac{x}{x_0}; \tag{13}$

we also thus have

$Q(x) = \dfrac{\ln x}{x}, \tag{14}$

whence

$\displaystyle \int_{x_0}^x \exp \left ( \int_{x_0}^s P(t) \; dt \right ) Q(s) \; ds = \int_{x_0}^x \dfrac{x_0}{s} \dfrac{\ln s}{s} \; ds = x_0 \int_{x_0}^x \dfrac{\ln s}{s^2} \; ds; \tag{15}$

the right-most integral is susceptible to integration by parts; setting

$u = \ln s; \; dv = s^{-2}ds, \tag{16}$

we have

$du = s^{-1} \;ds; \; v = -s^{-1}; \tag{17}$

$\displaystyle \int_{x_0}^x \dfrac{\ln s}{s^2} \; ds = \int_{x_0}^x u \; dv = uv \mid_{x_0}^x - \int_{x_0}^x v \; du = -s^{-1} \ln s \mid_{x_0}^x  - \int_{x_0}^x (-s^{-2}) \; ds$
$= \displaystyle \int_{x_0}^x (s^{-2}) \; ds - s^{-1} \ln s \mid_{x_0}^x = -s^{-1} \mid_{x_0}^x - s^{-1} \ln s \mid_{x_0}^x$$
= -\dfrac{1 + \ln s}{s} \mid_{x_0}^x = \dfrac{1 + \ln x_0}{x_0} - \dfrac{1 + \ln x}{x}; \tag{18}$

now returning to (15) we find

$\displaystyle \int_{x_0}^x \exp \left ( \int_{x_0}^s P(t) \; dt \right ) Q(s) \; ds = x_0 \left ( \dfrac{1 + \ln x_0}{x_0} - \dfrac{1 + \ln x}{x} \right ), \tag{19}$

and deploying (13) and (19) in (10) yields a solution for $z(x)$:

$z(x) = \dfrac{x}{x_0} \left (z(x_0) + x_0 \left ( \dfrac{1 + \ln x_0}{x_0} - \dfrac{1 + \ln x}{x} \right ) \right )$
$= \dfrac{z(x_0) x}{x_0} + x\left ( \dfrac{1 + \ln x_0}{x_0} - \dfrac{1 + \ln x}{x} \right ) = \dfrac{z(x_0) x}{x_0} + \dfrac{1 + \ln x_0}{x_0} x - (1 + \ln x)$
$ = \dfrac{z(x_0) + \ln x_0 + 1}{x_0} x - \ln x - 1; \tag{20}$

if we set

$K = \dfrac{z(x_0) + \ln x_0 + 1}{x_0}, \tag{21}$

then we may write

$z(x) = Kx - \ln x - 1; \tag{22}$

from (6) we have

$y(x) = e^{z(x)} = \exp(z(x)), \tag{23}$

whence

$y(x) = \exp(Kx - 1 - \ln x) = \exp(Kx - 1) \exp(-\ln x)$
$= \exp(Kx - 1) \exp(\ln x^{-1}) = \dfrac{\exp(Kx - 1)}{x}; \tag{24}$

we check:

$y'(x) = \dfrac{K \exp(Kx - 1) x - \exp(Kx - 1)}{x^2} = \dfrac{Kx - 1}{x^2} \exp(Kx - 1); \tag{25}$

$xy'(x) = \dfrac{Kx - 1}{x} \exp(Kx - 1); \tag{26}$

$xy(x) = \exp(Kx - 1); \tag{27}$

$y(x) \ln(xy(x)) = \dfrac{\exp(Kx - 1)}{x}(Kx - 1) = xy'(x). \tag{28}$

We have thus verified that (24) is the solution to (1).

Comment: I have to say you lost me I have not encountered the so called well known formula after $$z′+P(x)z=Q(x)$$. But i notice this is of the form where one can make use of an integrating factor correct? so mu = e^integral(-1/x)

Comment: The formula occurs in many places in elementary texts and on the internet; a nice example may be found herre-- https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0ahUKEwi8juin88TZAhUL3GMKHbzJDA4QFggxMAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.ucdavis.edu%2F~thomases%2FW11_16C1_lec_1_7_11.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2-p8_pLNS9XDooBqmCqmZE --  or at http://mathworld.wolfram.com/First-OrderOrdinaryDifferentialEquation.html -- it is basically derived by applying the integrating factor $e^{\int P \; dx}$ in general form, so in essence it is the same as using an integrating factor.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

That $\ln(xy)$ term really throws a monkey wrench into the works. If it were $\ln\left(\frac xy\right)$ the equation would be homogeneous and we would be home free. That suggests making the substitution $y=\frac1u$. Then
$$x\frac{dy}{dx}=x\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac1u\right)=-\frac x{u^2}\frac{du}{dx}=y\ln(xy)=\frac1u\ln\left(\frac xu\right)$$
Or
$$\frac{du}{dx}=-\frac ux\ln\left(\frac xu\right)$$
Now this is homogeneous so we let $u=vx$:
$$x\frac{dv}{dx}+v=-v\ln\left(\frac1v\right)=v\ln v$$
This is variables separable, so
$$\frac{dv}{v\ln v-v}=\frac{dx}x$$
Now, we will be in a lot of trouble if the substitution $v=e^z$ doesn't work, so we try it and hold our breath:
$$\frac{e^zdz}{e^z\cdot z-e^z}=\frac{dz}{z-1}=\frac{dx}x$$
Now we can integrate:
$$\ln|z-1|=\ln|x|+C_1$$
$$\begin{align}z-1&=\pm e^{C_1}x=Cx=\ln v-1=\ln\left(\frac ux\right)-1=\ln u-\ln x-1\\
&=\ln \left(\frac1y\right)-\ln x-1=-\ln y-\ln x-\ln e\end{align}$$
Exponentiating,
$$e^{Cx}=\frac1{exy}$$
$$y=\frac1xe^{-Cx-1}$$

Comment: thank you for your time